# How to write workflow for lead record when there is no activity performed

Tags: administration

How to write workflow for lead record when there is no activity performed on record till 10 days then send an email to owner automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem is as follows

1. Create a new field on Lead called number_of_tasks__c, defaulted to 0
2. Create an after (insert, delete) trigger on Task that increments (decrements) parent Lead.number_of_tasks__c
3. Create a time-based workflow on Lead that executes when number_of_tasks__c = 0 and has a time trigger at 10 days from `lead.createdDate`. The time triggers sends an email to the Lead.owner

So, all new Leads get a  time-based workflow created with a rule trigger at +10 days. As soon as the first task is created, the workflow is no longer true and the time trigger is removed.